# Can't open new project react native after create IOS

Tags: react-native

I user Xcode 10.4.
After create new project react native, I try open it on Xcode but I recevied note: can't open this project.

Answer (score 1):

From april 2021 you must use x-code 12. Update x-code and try again.

Comment: Thanks! I updated my x-code, and now i can open my project

Answer (score 0):

In order to open a React Native project on XCode, you juste have to open the XCode file project located on `ios/projectname.xcworkspace`